# cannot implicitly convert type int to model type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this query-

```
  var uploadedfile = (from u in db.CardTables
                                where u.CardID < cardtable.cardID
                                select new CardModel {
                                    cardID = cardtable.cardID,
                                    cardDate = cardtable.cardDate,
                                    cardFileName = cardtable.cardFileName,
                                    cardFilePath = cardtable.cardFilePath,
                                    cardHashCode = cardtable.cardHashCode,
                                    cardTitle = cardtable.cardTitle
                                }).ToList();
```

Where `cardID` is `int` type.

I am selecting last record from query match-

```
 CardModel previous = uploadedfile.Select(L => L.cardID).Last();
```

Where in this above line , this  gives me cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `cardmodel`.

**I tried converting it into int as-**

```
   CardModel previous = Convert.ToInt32(uploadedfile.Select(L => L.cardID).Last());
```

I wish to use `previous` in `tuple` with other table data as-

```
 var tuple = new Tuple<CardModel, List<TagModel>>(previous, taglist);
        return View(tuple);
```

What is the process of doing this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

```
uploadedfile.Select(L => L.cardID)
```

return collection of `int`, i.e. only value `cardID` fields

what you want get?
if last `CardModel` then you can use [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534502%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension without `Select`

```
CardModel previous = uploadedfile.Last();
```

if last `cardID` then you need change type for `previous` variable to `int`

```
int previous = uploadedfile.Select(L => L.cardID).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to get the `last` `CardModel` instance from `uploadedfile`, the following should suffice:

```
CardModel previous = uploadedfile.Last();
```